# Using a Timer Event for animation in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a simple city animation with a car going right across the screen and a ball rolling left. The animtion was run by the ENTER_FRAME event but I want to use a timer and I can't figure it out. Here's my code:

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.*;


public class cityApp extends MovieClip {
    function cityApp() {
        //TASK 1 : INITIALIZE THE MOVIECLIPS ON STAGE
        Car.x = 10;
        Ball.x = 500;
        Sunset.alpha = 0;

        //TASK 2: ADD A LISTENER TO LOOP THROUGH THE FRAME
        var atimer:Timer= new Timer(500, 30);
        atimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, CityMoves);
    }

    function CityMoves(event:TimerEvent):void {
        //TASK 1:  
        // A. DRIVE THE CAR ACROSS THE STAGE BY INCREMENTING ITS 
        // X POSITION BY 2
        Car.x += 2;
        //B. ROTATE THE WHEELS OF THE CAR
        Car.Wheel1.rotation+=3;
        Car.Wheel2.rotation+=3;

        //TASK 2: MOVE THE BALL IN THE OPPOSITE POSITION OF THE CAR
        //ROTATE THE BALL SO THAT IT APPEARS TO BE ROLLING
        Ball.x -= 2;
        Ball.rotation-= 5;

        //TASK 3:  THE EVENING SUNSET GRADUALLY APPEARS AS ITS ALPHA INCREASES.
        Sunset.alpha += .007;
    }
}
```

}
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should start timer.

```
atimer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

First make the timer a member variable (technically just make sure it you keep a live reference of it).  Then start it after setting it up:

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.*;


public class cityApp extends MovieClip {
    private var atimer:Timer; // change 1/3

    function cityApp() {
        //TASK 1 : INITIALIZE THE MOVIECLIPS ON STAGE
        Car.x = 10;
        Ball.x = 500;
        Sunset.alpha = 0;

        //TASK 2: ADD A LISTENER TO LOOP THROUGH THE FRAME
        atimer = new Timer(500, 30); // change 2/3
        atimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, CityMoves);
        atimer.start(); // change 3/3
    }

    function CityMoves(event:TimerEvent):void {
        //TASK 1:  
        // A. DRIVE THE CAR ACROSS THE STAGE BY INCREMENTING ITS 
        // X POSITION BY 2
        Car.x += 2;
        //B. ROTATE THE WHEELS OF THE CAR
        Car.Wheel1.rotation+=3;
        Car.Wheel2.rotation+=3;

        //TASK 2: MOVE THE BALL IN THE OPPOSITE POSITION OF THE CAR
        //ROTATE THE BALL SO THAT IT APPEARS TO BE ROLLING
        Ball.x -= 2;
        Ball.rotation-= 5;

        //TASK 3:  THE EVENING SUNSET GRADUALLY APPEARS AS ITS ALPHA INCREASES.
        Sunset.alpha += .007;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I just forgot to start the timer. Too much coffee or something this morning. :)